# Замена значений в SQL

Tags: sql-server

Нужно вставить/заменить в колонку часть значения из другой колонки. Например, есть значение одной колонки "Duplicata B02341543". В другую колонку нужно вставить только "B02341543". Для каждой строки слово "Duplicata" сохраняется, а, значение "B02341543" меняется.

Answer (score 2):

```
update table set field2=substring(field1,10,len(field1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE <YourTable> SET <updatedField> = SomeOperation(<someField>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name SET filed2 = SUBSTR(filed1,11);
```

11 - это длина слова "Duplicata" и пробел.